# Fetchxml throwing exception for checking not null values of a guid

Tags: javascript, guid, dynamics-crm-2016

I am trying to grab a list of invoices where `*customerid*` is not null. I generate fetchxml query from advanced find and then put into a function of XRMServiceToolkit but it throws following exception.

**Exception**

```
Error Code:-2147220989 Message: An exception System.FormatException was thrown while trying to convert input value 'not-null' to attribute 'invoice.customerid'. Expected type of attribute value: System.Guid. Exception raised: Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).
```

**Code Snippet**

Here is my code snippet.

```
function getinvoices()
{
var query = "<fetch mapping='logical' >"+
    "<entity name='invoice'>"+
        "<attribute name='name' >"+
        "<attribute name='customerid' >"+
        "<attribute name='statuscode' >"+
        "<attribute name='totalamount' >"+
        "<attribute name='invoiceid' >"+
    "<order attribute='name' descending='false' >"+
        "<filter type='and'>"+
            "<condition attribute='customerid' operator='not-null' >"+
        "</filter>"+
        "</entity>"+
"</fetch>";
    var retrievedInvoices = XrmServiceToolkit.Soap.RetrieveMultiple(query);

    alert(retrievedInvoices.length);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line should be `var retrievedInvoices = XrmServiceToolkit.Soap.Fetch(query);` for fetch queries.

Comment: I tried it but it throwing another exception that is "Object doesn't support property or method 'slice'"

Answer (score 0):

This fetch query doesn't have closing tags in most nodes. Try this:

```
<fetch mapping='logical' >
  <entity name='invoice' >
    <attribute name='name' />
    <attribute name='customerid' />
    <attribute name='statuscode' />
    <attribute name='totalamount' />
    <attribute name='invoiceid' />
    <order attribute='name' descending='false' />
    <filter type='and' >
      <condition attribute='customerid' operator='not-null' />
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```